# Facebook post search replacement

Tags: php, facebook

How can I replace Facebook post search, since it's returning the error 'Post search has been deprecated'?

Now I am using:

```
$result = $FacebookAPI->api('/search', 'GET', array(
        'q' => '#'.HASHTAG,
        'type' => 'post',
        'fields' => 'message,caption,object_id',
        'limit' => 1000
    ));
```

Is there are any easy way to renew the code?

Comment: You can’t, it is just not available any more.

Answer (score 0):

This April 30, 2015. Facebook upgraded app version v1.0 to v2.x and Deprecated public search by posts, you can search only with limited options, they are

check this

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search